# How do I download all versions of my Gradle dependencies?

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a project on my corporate network (which is offline) and I would like to setup Gradle to build it.

We have a Maven repository (Artifactory 4.0.2) which we want to use for dependency resolution, but we first need to import the dependencies from the global Internet into the corporate network.

I tried setting up a dummy hello world project on my home computer with all the dependencies defined in `build.gradle` and then build it, triggering dependency resolution and the download of all artifacts and their POM files into Gradle's cache (in `~/.gradle/caches`).

I then copied the whole Gradle cache into my computer at the corporate network, and before deploying everything to Artifactory I decided to try it out with a local Maven repository (in `~/.m2`). For that I created a script to create the appropriate `.m2/repository` folder from Gradle's cache.

When I tried building the actual project on the corporate network it failed at dependency resolution, saying it could not resolve one of the dependencies, for example:

```
> Could not find io.netty:netty:3.7.0.Final.
  Searched in the following locations:
      [...]/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.7.0.Final/netty-3.7.0.Final.pom
      [...]/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.7.0.Final/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar
  Required by:
      gradleTestProj:test:1.0 > org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.6.0-cdh5.4.0 > org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.6
```

The thing is, there really isn't such directory in Gradle's cache in my home computer, only `3.6.2.Final` (which contains only the POM file) and `3.8.0.Final` (which contains both the artifact and the POM file).

1. Is there a way to tell Gradle to download the POM file for the `3.7.0.Final` version as well?
2. Is there a way to tell Gradle to download ALL versions of the dependencies (so for above example, the artifact for the `3.6.2.Final` version would be downloaded as well as `3.7.0.Final`'s artifact and `3.8.0.Final` POM & artifact)?
3. Is there any better way to do that process of dependency resolution on my home computer (like an export of some sort) so I can import everything properly into my corporate network?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to import external dependencies into Artifactory. Artifactory will download them automatically from predefined repositories and put them inside its cache. You just need to configure Maven / Gradle to point to your Artifactory.

Comment: Our corporate Artifactory does not have Internet access either, so I cannot have it download the dependencies from repositories such as Maven central.

Comment: I am struggling to achieve the same thing, I need to populate artifactory some how from my laptop (gradle/maven cache) so that my build server that is not internet connected on my corporate network can resolve dependencies. How did you get the initial copy of the Gradle cache into artifactory?

Comment: @janh I created a dummy project on my home computer and built is using Gradle. To get it to download the dependencies I needed, I had the dummy project depend on the direct dependencies I needed for my project in the corporate network. I then copied over `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1` from my home computer to the corporate network, and ran a script on it that loops through all subdirs and copies pom/jar files from `{group}/{artifact}/{version}/{hash}/` to `{group}/{artifact}/{version}/`. It then split the `{group}` directories on dots (`a.b` -> `a/b`), then ran CURL on all files.

Comment: @janh The CURL command is: `curl -X PUT -u user:pass -T "path/to/local/file" "http://corporate-artifactory-server/artifactory/my-repo/path/to/local/file"` for example: `curl -X PUT -u user:pass -T "%userprofile%/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar" "http://corporate-artifactory-server/artifactory/my-repo/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar"`

Comment: I ended up using an Artifactory install on my internet connected corporate laptop, then exporting from that into an Artifactory install inside my corporate build environment (not internet connected).